# Why the attrTween doesn't work

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I trying to mimic an example from Mike Bostock [Extending Arcs](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/32bd93b1cc0fbccc9bf9). My code is very similar to Mike's, but mines doesn't work like his.

Here below is the JavaScript code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"> 
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Example</title>      
    <script src="static/d3.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
var Width = 500, Height = 400, innerRadius = 45, outerRadius = 100;
var colors = d3.scale.category10();

var svg = d3.select('body')
    .append('svg')
    .attr({ width: Width, height: Height });

var data = [40, 32, 35, 64, 83],
    pieData = d3.layout.pie()(data)

var ArcGen = d3.svg.arc()
    .innerRadius(innerRadius)
    .outerRadius(outerRadius)
    .padAngle(0.02)
    .startAngle(function(d){
        return d.startAngle;
    })
    .endAngle(function(d){
        return d.endAngle;
    });

var group = svg.append('g')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(' + [Width / 2.0, Height / 2.0] + ')');
var segment = group.selectAll('g')
    .data(pieData)
    .enter()
    .append('g');

segment
    .append('path')
    .attr('d', ArcGen)
    .attr('fill', function(d,i){ return colors(i); })
    .on('mouseover', arcTween(outerRadius * 1.2, 0))
    .on('mouseout', arcTween(outerRadius, 150));

function arcTween(oRadius, delay){
    // closure function
    return function(){
        d3.select(this)
            .transition()
            .delay(delay)
            .attrTween('d', function(d){
                var i = d3.interpolate(d.outerRadius, oRadius);
                return function(t){
                    d.outerRadius = i(t);
                    return ArcGen(d);
                }
            })
    };
};

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

This routine is simple, no error no action either.

I have two questions:

- If it's necessary to chain startAngle and endAngle attributes at every arc generator? I read some pros' code, such as Mike Bostock's, don't add this two attributes at the initial stage and their codes work fine when constructing path elements.
- Where am I wrong? is anybody can give me more attrTween examples.

Thanks, everyone!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code has 2 problems, that you can easily find comparing it with Bostock's code.

First, this line:

```
var i = d3.interpolate(d.outerRadius, oRadius);
```

Uses the property `outerRadius` in the element's datum. But it has none. You can fix this with:

```
.each(function(d) { d.outerRadius = outerRadius; })
```

Second, your arc generator is setting the outer radius:

```
var ArcGen = d3.svg.arc()
    .innerRadius(innerRadius)
    .outerRadius(outerRadius)
    .padAngle(0.02)
    .startAngle(function(d) {
        return d.startAngle;
    })
    .endAngle(function(d) {
        return d.endAngle;
    });
```

Remove it:

```
var ArcGen = d3.svg.arc()
    .innerRadius(innerRadius)
    .padAngle(0.02)
    .startAngle(function(d) {
        return d.startAngle;
    })
    .endAngle(function(d) {
        return d.endAngle;
    });
```

Here is your working code with the 2 changes:

```js
var Width = 500,
    Height = 400,
    innerRadius = 45,
    outerRadius = 100;
var colors = d3.scale.category10();

var svg = d3.select('body')
    .append('svg')
    .attr({
        width: Width,
        height: Height
    });

var data = [40, 32, 35, 64, 83],
    pieData = d3.layout.pie()(data)

var ArcGen = d3.svg.arc()
    .padAngle(0.02)
    .innerRadius(innerRadius)
    .startAngle(function(d) {
        return d.startAngle;
    })
    .endAngle(function(d) {
        return d.endAngle;
    });

var group = svg.append('g')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(' + [Width / 2.0, Height / 2.0] + ')');
var segment = group.selectAll('g')
    .data(pieData)
    .enter()
    .append('g');

segment
    .append('path')
    .each(function(d) {
        d.outerRadius = outerRadius;
    })
    .attr('d', ArcGen)
    .attr('fill', function(d, i) {
        return colors(i);
    })
    .on('mouseover', arcTween(outerRadius * 1.2, 0))
    .on('mouseout', arcTween(outerRadius, 150));

function arcTween(oRadius, delay) {
    // closure function
    return function() {
        d3.select(this)
            .transition()
            .delay(delay)
            .attrTween('d', function(d) {
                var i = d3.interpolate(d.outerRadius, oRadius);
                return function(t) {
                    d.outerRadius = i(t);
                    return ArcGen(d);
                }
            })
    };
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.17/d3.js"></script>
```